# Move Tscrollbox whit TMemo, TEdit.. how?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, tmemo, tscrollbox

Good evening, I have a problem in my FMX android Application  developed with Delphi XE6.
I have a TScrollBox and inside of it there are some TMemo.when you step on the TMemo I lose the focus on the scrollbox and does not move the scrollbox. how can I do?

Comment: Why would you expect the scroll box to move?

Comment: I have a TScrollBox, inside this there is a TMemo. the TMemo is larger than the screen. so I need that scrolling with your finger on the TMemo changes the position of the bars of tscrollbar

Comment: Er, finger? Perhaps you can explain where this code runs? Normally I'd assume this was a desktop VCL app. But perhaps not. Please try to make all this really clear in the question.

Comment: Why is the TMemo larger than the screen? You should be scrolling text in the TMemo, not a TScrollBox. TMemo has the ability to scroll text - it even has its own ScrollBars property. Also, is this VCL or FMX?

Comment: This is fmxandroid application

Comment: Please edit the question rather than providing the critical detail in comments

Comment: He cannot scroll anymore when he hits the TMemo component, as it takes over the scrolling. My advice would be, don't use a TMemo, but maybe it is better that the OP adds some screenshots so we can see the context?